# Add Value to the next sequence value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Cam anyone help me ?

I want to Add the value 10 (ID-1, Column_2) to the 150 (ID-2, column_1): such us: 10 +150 = 160

That process should repeat for every next row.

So the next will be  5+ 130 = 135.

Using SQL Select statement, can someone help me to write that code ?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  MySQL and SQL Server are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, you would use `lag()`:

```
select col1 + lag(col2, 1, 0) over (order by id) as col1, col2
from t;
```

This assumes that you do not want to change the first value.

Answer (score 1):

in sql server you can use inner join

```
    Create table #tmp(ID int,column_1 int, column_2 int)

    insert into #tmp values(1,100,10)
    insert into #tmp values(2,150,5)
    insert into #tmp values(3,130,20)

    select * from #tmp

    select  t1.column_2+t2.column_1 from #tmp t1
    INNER JOIN #tmp t2 on t1.Id=t2.Id-1

    DROP table #tmp
```